# Bash shell script that splits date into 3 arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, date

Hi I have an assignment that requires the user to enter their date of birth.
From the beginning I need to get the user to input their date of birth.
Let' say if the date entered is "20050215", how can I split it into 3 arguments? (2005 02 15)
I also need for user to have other option to input their birthday like this 
"-y 2005 -m 02 -d 15"
Please help me.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Bash provides excellent *string-indexing* that allows you to do just what you need:

```
bdate=20050215

year=${bdate:0:4}
mon=${bdate:4:2}
day=${bdate:6:2}
```

The format is `${var:start:length}` If you need to offset from the *end*, then you either leave a *space* before the start (e.g. `${var: -2:1}` for next to last char), or you enclose the negative offset in parenthesis (e.g. `${var:(-2):1}` -- for the same next to last char).

You can create a small script that takes the input without much of a problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "enter birthdate (yyyymmdd): "
read bdate

[ "${#bdate}" -ne "8" ] && {
    printf "error: invalid length of date entered.\n"
    exit 1
}

[[ ${bdate} =~ [^0-9] ]] && {
    printf "error: non digit in date entered.\n"
    exit 1
}

year=${bdate:0:4}
mon=${bdate:4:2}
day=${bdate:6:2}

printf "date entered: %s\n\n" "$bdate"
printf "  year  : %s\n" "$year"
printf "  month : %s\n" "$mon"
printf "  day   : %s\n\n" "$day"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash ymd_split.sh
enter birthdate (yyyymmdd): 20050215
date entered: 20050215

  year  : 2005
  month : 02
  day   : 15


$ bash ymd_split.sh
enter birthdate (yyyymmdd): 1234567
error: invalid length of date entered.


$ bash ymd_split.sh
enter birthdate (yyyymmdd): 1234567a
error: non digit in date entered.
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, your suggestion really helped. Appreciated :)

Comment: Sure, glad I could help. Now make sure you understand it all, and if you have questions, just ask. The tests are what are known as *compound commands*. They are used as an abbreviated `if` above (it just saves having to write the entire `if then else fi`. Make sure you understand the difference between the `[` and the `[[` conditional statements and when quoting is/isn't required inside them, etc.. There is a lot going on in the short little script. Good luck with your scripting. Scripting in bash, zsh, etc.. is a very capable form of programming.

Comment: Yeah I'm quite new to this whole thing so I haven't fully grasped the concept but I'm glad you could help. Best wishes.

Comment: Being new, you will want to spend (a lot of) time at [**BashGuide - Greg's Wiki**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide). It is a well written very useful collection of everything bash. Look closely at the [**Bash FAQ**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and most importantly the [**Bash Pitfalls**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) page.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't want to validate dates yourself (i.e. leap years) you should use `date`.

```
bdate=20160229
d=$(date --date="$bdate" +%d)
m=$(date --date="$bdate" +%m)
y=$(date --date="$bdate" +%Y)
```

Comment: Why three separate date calls, rather than only one with `read` used to split the results? ie. `read d m y < <(date -d "$bdate" '+%d %m %y')`. Much more efficient; exec'ing external calls is *expensive*

Comment: ...you could perhaps do even better if you were guaranteed bash 4.3, which has `strftime` support built into its `printf`.